# How to make sure a list have certain necessary values?

Tags: java

I need to have a `ArrayList of ArrayList<Integer>` which if index 0 has {1,4} then index 1 and 4 should also have 0 in their list. And vice versa, if 1 is deleted from list of index 0, then index 1 should also delete 0 from its list.

Something like  if `john` is friend with `mark` and `elizabeth` then mark and elizabeth have list of their own friends plus `john` in their list.

Any suggestion? It should not be necessarily ArrayList, that is my guess only.

Comment: For "marriage", try using HashMap's.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: Wh are you keeping both lists and not just one?

Comment: In what context are you trying to do this in? I'm mocking up a sketch for you now.

Comment: Because I have list of names of friends, so if `john` is friend with `mark` and `elizabeth` then mark and elizabeth have list of their own friends plus `john` in their list, so it should be multiple lists.

Comment: Don't implement complex interdependent data structures as lists; in an OO language, you build a class for that.

Comment: It almost sounds like you want a list of relationships. Eg. class RelationShip{ String a; String b;}; Otherwise you will be keeping trying to keep numerous lists up to date.

Comment: @frayment It is a common technique. You're quasi-example doesn't support or disprove it. I posted the comment for the OP as a suggestion.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## (Bad) implementation using HashMap

First of all, you want a class representing each person you have, with a list for containing their friends:

```
public class Person {   
    String name;

    // For identification purposes.
    public Person(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    HashMap<String, Person> friends = new HashMap<String, Person>();
}
```

Now you want to add the following methods to the class, to allow you to add/remove friends:

```
public void addFriend(Person person) {
    if (friends.get(person.name) == null) friends.put(person.name, person);
    person.friends.put(name, this);
}

public void removeFriend(Person person) {
    if (friends.get(person.name) != null) friends.remove(person.name);
    person.friends.remove(name);
}

// Only add this to test and see the list of friends.
public void printFriends() {
    System.out.println(name + "'s Friends:");
    for (Person p : friends.values()) {
        System.out.println("    " + p.name);
    }
}
```

Thats your person setup! Now you need to start using the newly created people!

```
public class PersonTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Person johndoe = new Person("John Doe");
        Person janedoe = new Person("Jane Doe");
        Person danedoe = new Person("Dane Doe");

        johndoe.addFriend(janedoe);
        janedoe.addFriend(danedoe);

        johndoe.printFriends();
        janedoe.printFriends();
        danedoe.printFriends();
    }
}
```

**Output: (Formatted for Stack Exchange)**

> John Doe's Friends:
>       * Jane Doe
>   Jane Doe's Friends:
>       * John Doe
>       * Dane Doe
>   Dane Doe's Friends:
>       * Jane Doe

## (Better) implementation using HashMap and UUID's.

You should be changing/shaping the `Person` class as needed. The only reason `name` exists however in the previous implementation, is to be able to identify the person in the HashMap. The problem with this, is that two "John Smith"'s may exist. Adding in the second John, will overwrite the previous iteration. Therefore, you should change `name` in `addFriend()` and `removeFriend()` to a UUID generated per-person instead.

```
public class Person {
    String uuid = UUID.randomUUID().toString();

    HashMap<String, Person> friends = new HashMap<String, Person>();

    public void addFriend(Person person) {
        if (friends.get(person.uuid) == null) friends.put(person.uuid, person);
        person.friends.put(uuid, this);
    }

    public void removeFriend(Person person) {
        if (friends.get(person.uuid) != null) friends.remove(person.uuid);
        person.friends.remove(uuid);
    }

    public void printFriends() {
        System.out.println(uuid + "'s Friends:");
        for (Person p : friends.values()) {
            System.out.println("    " + p.uuid);
        }
    }
}
```

## (Best) implementation using HashSet directly

Although the above two implementations work*, they introduce bad programming habits, and chew up performance (*albeit small*). Using a `HashSet`, entirely removes the need to include UUID's or any other form of identifier, as the `Set` can be communicated with **directly**, without the need for a Key.

**first implementation has no duplicate handling.*

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String name) {this.name = name;}

    Set<Person> friends = new HashSet<Person>();

    public void addFriend(Person person) {
        friends.add(person);
        person.friends.add(this);
    }

    public void removeFriend(Person person) {
        friends.remove(person);
        person.friends.remove(this);
    }

    public void printFriends() {
        System.out.println(name + "'s Friends:");
        for (Person p : friends) {
            System.out.println("    " + p.name);
        }
    }
}
```

**PS: The `PersonTest` class works universally for all 3 implementations.**

Answer (score 0):

My take would be:

- Create a class for `Friendship` holding the two `Person`s in a symmetrical way (in terms of `equals()` and `hashCode()`), i.e. `new Friendship('Mark, 'Frank').equals(new Friendship('Frank', 'Mark'))`
- Create class `Friendships` that manages the relations:

  - Hold a `Set<Friendship>`, a set of all existing friendships
  - Provides methods for adding new relations and deleting relation when given both "ends" (it's a `Set`, so these would be efficient)
  - If you also need to access friends of the given person, add an index by person

    - Data structure would be `Map<Person, Set<Friendship>>`
    - This index would need to be updated whenever a relationship is added or removed

---

What we're talking about basically is an undirected graph, with vertices being persons and edges representing friendships. My representation of the graph above effectively uses edge set, a representation in another answer uses adjecency list.

For any bigger project, it would probably be a good idea to read on representing graphs and perhaps use an existing graph library.

Comment: But now you're introducing another class, even though it delegates all friendships. If @secret was to create lets say a social networking website, you have just delegated every single users friendship into a single mapping, opposed to seperate mappings per-person. Although  (possibly) more efficient, your model is less secure.

Comment: @frayment I admit that my approach is closer to a database design than OO. I would think both my and your approach would be similar in term of efficiency. I would like to know more on your concern regarding security (do you mean info security or security against programming errors?).

Comment: @frayment bit unfair you're hitting on `Jiri Tousek`s answer when you're wasn't completely useful in the first place.

Comment: @Popeye I'm not necessarily attacking him at all. Mine was already accepted by the time Jiri's was created and just explained the difference from the accepted answer. I don't see how it wasn't useful though?

Comment: @frayment No offense taken, this is well within boundaries of constructive criticism in my book.

Comment: @frayment as for info sec, if this is a concern you'd probably have a system big enough that you'd have to store the relations in some database anyway. Info security then could be better served by loading only the appropriate data from DB in the first place.

Comment: @JiriTousek Well I probably looked drunk when I was talking about Informational Security. The **correct** statement, is "there is no need to incorporate delegation, when it's on a personal **my** friends "level". If the OP is creating a handler which takes care of **everyones** friends, then your model is **definitely** the correct way to go. As for criticism, I'm sorry if I came off threatening. I certainly didn't mean to.